# How to add default field names in Portia scrapy drop down list?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, portia

I have downloaded Portia from (https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia) and installed Portia in my windows machine, while start Portia I can able to annotate the page.

[image: how to add default fields drop down list]

I can able to select the fields and add name as I needed using create new option.

My question is how can we add default Fields names, so that instead of typing the name I shall be able select it from drop down box, and also it would be generic.

for example,

In the drop down i need list of field names like,

JobTitle,
JobDescription,
JobLocation

Can anyone help me, how to add the filed names by default instead of create new option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new field it will be available within the dropdown the next time you want to use it. You will only need to type it once.

If you would like to define your item, add fields and specify if they are required or if they vary, you can do so by opening the 'Extracted Item' tab and clicking on 'Edit Item'. This will allow you to add many fields at once without having to use create new while annotating.

To move an item between projects you can copy the items.json file from one project to another which will make all of the items from that project available in the new project.

Comment: But If I open new project then the field list is not available there.

Comment: Items are created on a per project basis. You can copy the items.json file to the new project if you wish to use it there.

Comment: Yes ,that is also one possible solution.

Comment: For now it is the only solution but we are investigating other options for moving spiders, items and extractors between projects.